# How to add a feature like "Global Achievements" on Steam to app

Tags: python, swift, database, kotlin, steam

I'm creating my simple application in Python. There are several achievements in the application and I want to know how many people (application users) have completed these achievements in total. Also so that each user can see how many people have completed this achievement. There is such a system on Steam[Steam, Global Achievements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBPNM.png). I would like to add such a system of global achievements to other platforms (Android, IOS) using other programming languages (if this matters)

I'm new to app development and there are some things I don't know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.